# Javascript innerhtml doesn't work with twig tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, innerhtml

I have a function in twig which selects some values from db and displays a selectbox. I am trying to change the content of the div. The problem is that with innerHTML {{ creates a new line without quote and this is shown like error. It doesnt get the select box because it doesn't have quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
               $type = $("select[name='dtl[USER_TYPE]']");

               $type.change(function() {

                   if ($(this).val() == "AUTOR") {
                       var content = '{{ mm.select(holdersdata, data.USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD, 'dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]')  }}';
                       document.getElementById("kodi").innerHTML = '"'+ content + '"';
                   }
               });
           });
```

macros.twig

```
<select data-placeholder="{{ translate('ZGJIDH_NJE') }}" name="{{ name }}" class="form-control input-sm chosen-select">
        <option {% if not options.allowNull %}disabled{% endif %} selected value>{{ translate('ZGJIDH_NJE') }}</option>
        {% for f in dataset %}
            <option value="{{ f[kodField] }}" {% if f[kodField] | trim == selectedVal %}selected{% endif %}>
                {% if f[labelField] %}
                    {{ f[labelField] }} {% if f[kodField] %}&mdash; ({{ f[kodField] }}){% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    {{ f[kodField] }}
                {% endif %}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

EDIT
this is shown in console. {{ creates a new line without quotes:

```
 var content = "        
    <select data-placeholder="Zgjidh nje..." name="dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]" class="form-control input-sm chosen-select">
        <option disabled selected value>Zgjidh nje...</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: just wrap `var content` with double quotes and not single

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your twig syntax is breaking the javascript syntax. See below, just change the `'`to `"`

```
               if ($(this).val() == "AUTOR") {
                   var content = '{{ mm.select(holdersdata, data.USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD, 'dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]')  }}';
                   document.getElementById("kodi").innerHTML = '"'+ content + '"';
               }
```

Correct code :

```
           if ($(this).val() == "AUTOR") {
               var content = "{{ mm.select(holdersdata, data.USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD, 'dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]')  }}";
               document.getElementById("kodi").innerHTML = '"'+ content + '"';
           }
```

Due to the contents of your output JS is breaking as well. U can solve this by extending twig :

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('escape_for_js', function ($string) {
    $needles= array(
       "\n",
       "\r",
       '"',
    );
    $replaces = array(
      '',
      '',
      '\"',
    );
    return str_replace($needles, $replaces, $string);
});
```

Add this filter into twig :

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter
```

Using this filter :

```
var content = "{{ mm.select(holdersdata, data.USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD, 'dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]') | escape_for_js }}";
```

More about extending twig [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html)

Comment: just edited my question with error that is shown in console. Even with your answer

Comment: I see. U should write a twig filter that replaces all linebreaks with nothing and all " with \"

Comment: @jojo added an example filter

Answer (score 0):

No need to extend Twig yourself. Just use [`json_encode`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html):

```
var content = {{ mm.select(holdersdata, data.USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD, 'dtl[USER_TYPE_OBJECT_KOD]') | json_encode }};
```

Notice the lack of quotes. json_encode will add them for you.